# Create ListPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a ListPreference in Android. But instead of creating all in XML i want to add the Entries and EntriesValues in JAVA. I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ListPreference android:key="delay"
        android:title="@string/settings_push_delay"
        android:defaultValue="Default">
    </ListPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then i have this class, extending PreferenceActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("delay");

        listPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

    }

public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            ListPreference lp = (ListPreference)preference;
            String[] array={"1","2","3"};
            CharSequence[] entries = array;
            CharSequence[] entryValues = array;
            lp.setEntries(entries);
            lp.setDefaultValue("1");
            lp.setEntryValues(entryValues);
            return true;

    }
```

This is just a test that i'm trying to do, so i can fully understand how to create Preferences dynamically.

Forgot to say that i've having exceptions while running this code:

```
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.preference.ListPreference.onPrepareDialogBuilder(ListPreference.java:232)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:293)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:264)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:939)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:202)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-14 00:47:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My question is, how i create a ListPreference without defining the Entries and EntryValues on the XML. How can do that in JAVA file. So, how i solve this exceptions?

Thanks,

Comment: Please ask a question. Also, if you have exceptions, you must provide the stack trace(s) (from logcat). Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot be setting the `entries` and `entryValues` of the `ListPreference` in an `onClick` event when there are no `entries` and `entryValues` to begin with.

Instead do it in the `onCreate`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("delay");
    String[] array={"1","2","3"};
    CharSequence[] entries = array;
    CharSequence[] entryValues = array;
    listPreference.setEntries(entries);
    listPreference.setDefaultValue("1");
    listPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues);
}
```

Then if you need set values dynamically in onClick listener, it should work okay.

Comment: Still have the same exceptions

Comment: what should i put in the onClick listener?

Comment: @user3211283 if you just need to load the list once, you don't need an onClick listener, as the list should be set when loaded in onCreate. Are you sure you are getting the same exceptions? Works okay for me.

Comment: yes, everytime i click on that preference instead of appear the "1", "2", "3" list. gives me the exception that ListPreference needs to have entries and EntryValue.

There's another way to do this?

Comment: @user3211283 did you remove your onclick listener?

Comment: yes, i remove it. right now i only have the OnCreate method, as you said

by the way, in this scenario when should i use the listener?

Comment: @user3211283 you would use the onclick if you want to change the entries based on some condition. Weird it doesn't work since it works fine for me (2.3.3 and 4.4.2). Are you sure you are building the app and not using an old copy? Uninstall and reinstall maybe?

Comment: sorry, i was using another copy of this. after i changed as you said worked great :D thanks a lot

Comment: @user3211283 No problem! I thought I was going crazy that it wasn't working!